# htaccess Causing Google Issues

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm not a programmer and I'm struggling to work out what is wrong with our .htaccess file.

Google is indexing pages on both www.domain.co.uk & domain.co.uk  I thought that the way the .htaccess was written would take care of this, but it doesn't. (webmaster tools set to www. for preferred & canonical link on each page).

Secondly I ran a performance check on Zoompf & it gave lots of findings, many of which are htaccess based.

If someone could cast an eye over the file below (with added notes) and please give me some pointers I would really appreciate it?

Many thanks

Dave

#### Added this first line to stop Google listing the folder indexes

```
options -Indexes
```

#### Added this to try and stop orders coming in from cached pages

```
<FilesMatch ".(html|htm|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600"
</FilesMatch>
```

#### /sexy & /pages were old directories superceded by /underwear

```
Redirect /sexy http://www.blushlingerie.co.uk/underwear
Redirect /pages http://www.blushlingerie.co.uk/underwear
```

#### Not sure where this came from but I think it's from our Wordpress Blog

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .html
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
```

#### I think the problem lies here.  This is supposed to take care of cononical problems

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^blushlingerie.co.uk [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.blushlingerie.co.uk/$1 [r=301,nc] 
options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.blushlingerie.co.uk [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

For your index issue

```
options -Indexes
```

Should be

```
Options -Indexes
```

Wordpress's .htaccess [should only be](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Removing the www [can be done](http://txt.binnyva.com/2008/09/remove-www-from-url-using-htaccess-in-apache/) like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```